# Gerund vs Perfect Gerund

Tags: gerunds

The task is on translating. I want to know is it acceptable to use Perfect Gerund (action of the Gerund has happened before the main action) instead of Gerund.

> "I've been a bad wife to him", - she thought. "Just yesterday I scolded him for not wiping/not having wiped his feet before he entered the kitchen. I'll never see him again."

Comment: You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before". So "not wiping his feet before he entered the kitchen" is fine. In any case, there are no so-called gerunds anywhere to be seen.

Comment: I vote to close this question because although it asks about the gerund, there are no gerunds in the text.